# Visual Studio 2012 UI Bug Fix?

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, visual-studio-2012

[image: QuickWatch UI]

[image: Break Point Condition]

I am having some issues with my Visual Studio 2012 UI. When I try to perform various functions (QuickWatch, Break Point Conditions, etc) The text boxes in the UI are filled with what look like scrambled images and I cannot type anything legible into them.

Anyone experiencing similar behavior and know how to fix it? It basically means these functions are useless to me right now.

Comment: have you tried moving the window past the edge of the screen and then moving it back?

Comment: I have moved it everywhere, I have three monitors.

Comment: Try using only one monitor and see if you can reproduce this bug. Once you have a reproducible case, report it to Microsoft so it can be fixed.

Comment: Pretty sure it is not a monitor issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Go to TOOLS --> OPTIONS --> ENVIRONMENT --> GENERAL

Unselect Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance

Unselect Use hardware graphics acceleration if available.

Problem solved.